# React eventListener not being called during scroll(React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, addeventlistener

I'm trying to use my **useScrollPosition()** hooks in my main app. It's used to adjust the container's height depending on the scroll position.

Problem: When I scroll down, the **useScrollPosition()** isnt being called.

Here's the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-khorana-5yffl?file=/src/App.js

Please help me get my **useScrollPosition()** hook to work again. I have a feeling it is due to my fixed position styling, or the way I'm calling the eventListener.

**My code:**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      });
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);
  return windowSize;
};
const useScrollPosition = () => { // error is probably here
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    x: window.scrollX,
    y: window.scrollY
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      console.log("test");

      setPosition({
        x: window.scrollX,
        y: window.scrollY
      });
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    handleScroll();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);
  return position;
};

const appContainerStyle = {
  position: "fixed",
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "flex-end",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  overflowY: "scroll"
};

export default function App() {
  const size = useWindowSize();
  const position = useScrollPosition();

  const containerStyle = {
    position: "relative",
    height: size.width <= 1024 && size.height <= 1366 ? "100%" : "50%",
    width: "100%"
  };
  const contentContainerStyle = {
    height: position.y <= size.height / 10 ? "90%" : "100%",
    width: "100%"
  };
  const navContainerStyle = {
    position: "fixed",
    height: position.y <= size.height / 10 ? "10%" : "0%",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
    zIndex: "1",
    top: "0"
  };
  console.log(position.y, size.height / 10);
  return (
    <div style={appContainerStyle}>
      <div style={navContainerStyle}></div>
      <div style={contentContainerStyle}>
        <div style={{ ...containerStyle, backgroundColor: "red" }}></div>
        <div style={{ ...containerStyle, backgroundColor: "green" }}></div>
        <div style={{ ...containerStyle, backgroundColor: "blue" }}></div>
        <div style={{ ...containerStyle, backgroundColor: "orange" }}></div>
        <div style={{ ...containerStyle, backgroundColor: "purple" }}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not scrolling inside the `window`, but inside the `appContainer`.

You need to add the event listener to the `appContainer`. That can be done with a ref:

```
    const myScrollBox = useRef(null);
    const position = useScrollPosition( myScrollBox.current );
// ...
        <div id="mainContainer" style={ appContainerStyle } ref={ myScrollBox }>
```

Inside `useScrollPosition` you need to make sure the component has been rendered already:

```
const useScrollPosition = ( elementRef ) => { // <-- pass the element ref
    const [ position, setPosition ] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    const [ element, setElement ] = useState(null);

    // -- set DOM element, if ref is ready and element is not set already
    useEffect(() =>{
        if( elementRef && !element ){
            setElement( elementRef );
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {

        if( !element ){ return; }      // <-- skip if element is not ready

        const handleScroll = () => {
            setPosition({
                x: element.scrollTop,  // <-- .scrollTop instead of .scrollY
                y: element.scrollLeft  // <-- .scrollLeft instead of .scrollX
            });
        };

        element.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
 
        return () => { element.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll); };
    }, [ element ]);            // <-- add element to dependencies

    return position;
};
```